# How to use eos-sharp with ASP.NET Core web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, blockchain, eos

I am writing web API to get users data from multi-index table data. Below is my API method:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async IAsyncEnumerable<GetTableRowsResponse>  GetUsers()
            //public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUsers()
        {
            Eos eos = new Eos(new EosConfigurator()
            {
                HttpEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain", //running nodeos on localhost
                ChainId = "nodeoschainid",
                ExpireSeconds = 60,
                SignProvider = new DefaultSignProvider("MyPK")
            });

            var result = await eos.GetTableRows(new GetTableRowsRequest()
            {
                json = true,
                code = "groupacc",
                scope = "groupacc",
                table = "users"
            });

            yield return result;
        }
```

This is throwing exception:

> ApiErrorException: Exception of type 'EosSharp.Core.Exceptions.ApiErrorException' was thrown.

I have users data in multi-index table **users** and return all users from API. can anybody help me with the error and return types? Also I am not sure about return type **IAsyncEnumerable** and **yield return** with async.

Comment: Try remove `yield` before `return result` and change method return type to `Task<IEnumerable<GetTableRowsResponse>>`

Comment: Hi..I tried this but still giving explicit type conversion error. As the return type of result variable is GetTableRowsResponse

Comment: Basically the code is throwing exception after var result = await eos.GetTableRows(new GetTableRowsRequest(). I checked same code runs in another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `JsonConvert`. The complete code is below:

```
public async Task<string> GetUsers(string code, string scope, string table)
{
            try
            {
                Eos eos = new Eos(new EosConfigurator()
                {
                   HttpEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain", 
                   ChainId = "nodeoschainid",
                   ExpireSeconds = 60,
                   SignProvider = new DefaultSignProvider("MyPK")
                });
                GetTableRowsResponse result = await eos.GetTableRows(new GetTableRowsRequest()
                {
                    json = true,
                    code = "groupacc",
                    scope = "groupacc",
                    table = "users"
                });

                string resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.rows);
                return resultJson;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
  }
```